# Create a list from user input in Prolog

Tags: sorting, merge, prolog, user-input

I am having trouble how to do this on prolog

The program will ask Input a number of elements: 6

Then the user will input 6 numbers `, 4, 3, 6, 2, 9, 10`

Then the prolog will sort into an ascending manner

Sorted List: `2 3 4 6 9 10`

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Enter the first Six digits using read.

**2-** Place them all in a List. List=[X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6]

**3-** Now use the built-in sort predicate. You can use any 1 of them sort/2 arguments, or sort/4 arguments. The difference between the two is that in sort/2 it will remove the repeating values ([4,1,5,5,2] -> [1,2,4,5]), and in sort/4 it keeps the repeated values ([4,1,5,5,2] -> [1,2,4,5,5]).

```
start:-
    writeln('Enter First digit'),
    read(X1),
    writeln('Enter Second digit'),
    read(X2),
    writeln('Enter Third digit'),
    read(X3),
    writeln('Enter Fourth digit'),
    read(X4),
    writeln('Enter Fifth digit'),
    read(X5),
    writeln('Enter Sixth digit'),
    read(X6),
    List=[X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6],
   % sort(List,Sorted),
    sort(0,@=<,List,Sorted),
    write('Sorted:'),write(Sorted).
```

**Example:**

```
?- start.
Enter First digit
4
Enter Second digit
1
Enter Third digit
5
Enter Fourth digit
5
Enter Fifth digit
2
Enter Sixth digit
8
Sorted: [1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 8]
1true
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the number of elements may vary, a possible solution is:

```
main :-
    writeln('Number of items? '),
    read(N),
    length(L, N),
    maplist(read, L),
    sort(L, S),
    format('Sorted list: ~w~n', [S]).
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Another question, can I implement this merge sort code into the sort code 

`mergesort([], []).
mergesort([A], [A]).
mergesort([A, B|R], S) :-
split([A, B|R], L1, L2),
mergesort(L1, S1),
mergesort(L2, S2),
merge(S1, S2, S).

split([],[],[]).
split([A], [A],[]).
split([A, B|R], [A|Ra], [B|Rb]) :-
split(R, Ra, Rb).

merge(A, [], A).
merge([], B, B).
merge([A|Ra], [B|Rb], [A|M]) :-
A =< B, merge(Ra, [B|Rb], M).
merge([A|Ra], [B|Rb], [B|M]) :-
A > B, merge([A|Ra], Rb, M). `

Comment: @seungcheol You can alter predicate ```main``` to call ```mergesort(L,S)```, instead of ```sort(L,S)```.